# Topology on the set of transport maps

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

I have a question about the following:

Given two Polish spaces $X$ and $Y$ with probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined on their Borel-$\sigma$-algebras, respectively.

Why is there no possibility to endow the set $T(\mu,\nu):=\{T:X\rightarrow Y\text{ measurable }; T_\#\mu = \nu\}$ with a topology such that $T(\mu,\nu)$ is sequentially closed and compact, where $T_\#\mu(B) := \mu(T^{-1}(B))$ with $B\subseteq Y$ measurable?

Thanks for every idea, hint or explanation!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the source of this claim ?

Comment: This question arises if you try to solve Monge's problem with variational methods. In the book "Lectures on Optimal Transport"  by Ambrosio etc. he claims that this is not possible (p. 10).